Building a Table by Enumerating Rows
Consider the following table

I need to quickly add/delete/exchange rows, and the number is automatically enumerated just like in the enumerate environment. Adding new columns is also needed, though rarely. (If number of columns is fixed to four, that's good enough). The content of the cells can include a whole paragraph, equations, and pictures.
I am looking for a package to write such table where the user interface would look something like this:
\enumeratetablesettings{... } % settings for widths, lines, # of columns, etc.
\thetablehead{No.}{Name}{Fruit}{Qty}
\begin{enumeratetable}
  \itemrow{ Alice }{ Lemon }{ 9 }
  \itemrow{ Bob }{ Durian }{ 6 }
  \itemrow{ Cindy }{ Strawberry }{ 8 }
\end{enumeratetable}

Here is the code to manually make the table above
\begin{tabular}{| c | c |  c | c |}
  \hline
  No. & Name & Fruit & Qty \\
  \hline \hline
  1 & Alice & Lemon & 9 \\
  \hline 
  2 & Bob & Durian & 6 \\
  \hline 
  3 & Cindy & Strawberry & 8 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

Edit: There are similar questions. But I think mine is different; it asks for a cell-wise macro (alongside the enumerate issue). I've now made the requested user interface question bold.
Thanks!

Please don't post code fragments. Instead put the partial code into a compilable document that people can play with.

The tabularray package has build in support to number rows, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720303/36296 for an example

The linked-to question only addresses automatic row numbering.  But the OP here explicitly states the question is not limited to only that.  Hence this is not a duplicate.

An anternative using tabularray and functional packages. It is not very lightweight, but the programation is, imho, easier to follow.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{functional,booktabs}
% Function
\IgnoreSpacesOn
\prgNewFunction \RowNumbering { } {
    \intStepOneInline { 2 } { \arabic{rowcount} } {
        \cellSetText { ##1 } { 1 } {
            \intEval { ##1 - 1 }
        }
    }
}
\NewDocumentEnvironment {enumeratetable} {O{} +b} {
    \vspace{6pt}
    \begin{tblr}[
        expand=\itemrow\theTableHead,
        ]{
        colspec = {cccc},
        process = \RowNumbering,
        #1
        }
        \toprule
        \theTableHead
        \midrule
        #2
        \bottomrule
        \end{tblr}
    }{
        \vspace{6pt}
    }

\newcommand {\theTableHead} {No&Name&Fruit&Qty\\}
\newcommand {\itemrow} [3] {&#1&#2&#3&\\}
\newcommand {\setTableHead} [4] {
    \renewcommand {\theTableHead} {#1&#2&#3&#4\\}
}

\IgnoreSpacesOff

\begin{document}
    
\setTableHead{N°}{Name}{Fruit}{Qty}
\begin{enumeratetable}
    \itemrow{ Alice }{ Lemon }{ 9 }
    \itemrow{ Bob }{ Durian }{ 6 }
    \itemrow{ Cindy }{ Strawberry }{ 8 }
    \itemrow{ Duncan }{ Banana }{ 3 }
    \itemrow{ Edith }{ Apple }{ 10 }
\end{enumeratetable}

Another example

\setTableHead{\#}{Person}{Item}{Total}
\begin{enumeratetable}[
    colspec = cXXX,
    width = 0.75\linewidth,
    row{odd} = {bg=blue!15},
    row{even} = {bg=blue!5},
    row{1} = {font=\bfseries},
    ]
    \itemrow{ Alice }{ Beef }{ 9 }
    \itemrow{ Bob }{ Coffee }{ 6 }
    \itemrow{ Cindy }{ Eggs }{ 8 }
    \itemrow{ Duncan }{ Bacon }{ 3 }
\end{enumeratetable}
\end{document}



With tabularray is much simpler than your answer, it automatically counts rows see, for example: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/720303/101651.

With a very simple user level syntax (the code is admittedly not so simple):
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{enumtabular}{ob}
 {% #1 = optional column specifications
  % #2 = table body
  \__fajar_enumtabular_body:nn {#1} {#2}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fajar_enumtabular_body:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq {\\} {#2}
  % check whether there's a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {% last item not blank, put it back
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  % startup
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
   {% no column specification, center
    % count the number of columns
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_put_left:NV \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { & } \l_tmpa_tl
    % start
    \begin{tabular}{|c|*{\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}{c|}}
   }
   {% columns after the first are specified
    \seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {} {#1}
    \exp_args:Nne \begin{tabular}{|c|\seq_use:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {|}|}
   }
  \hline
  % process the rows
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \__fajar_enumtabular_row:nn
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fajar_enumtabular_row:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 1 }
   {
    No. & #2 \\ \hline\hline
   }
   {
    \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } & #2 \\ \hline
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumtabular}
  Name & Fruit & Qty \\
  Alice & Lemon & 9 \\
  Bob & Durian & 6 \\
  Cindy & Strawberry & 8
\end{enumtabular}

\bigskip

\begin{enumtabular}[llc]
  Name & Fruit & Qty \\
  Alice & Lemon & 9 \\
  Bob & Durian & 6 \\
  Cindy & Strawberry & 8
\end{enumtabular}

\end{document}

The basic idea is to split the body at \\ and to isolate the first row (with index 1). This is used to count the number of columns (if the optional argument is not used) and instead of the index in the first column, we print “No.”.
Then all rows are processed.
See the difference when the optional argument is specified.

Now the changes to make the tables a lot prettier.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentEnvironment{enumtabular}{ob}
 {% #1 = optional column specifications
  % #2 = table body
  \__fajar_enumtabular_body:nn {#1} {#2}
 }{}

\seq_new:N \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fajar_enumtabular_body:nn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq {\\} {#2}
  % check whether there's a trailing \\
  \seq_pop_right:NN \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
  \tl_if_blank:VF \l_tmpa_tl
   {% last item not blank, put it back
    \seq_put_right:NV \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
   }
  % startup
  \tl_if_novalue:nTF {#1}
   {% no column specification, center
    % count the number of columns
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_put_left:NV \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \l_tmpa_tl
    \seq_set_split:NnV \l_tmpa_seq { & } \l_tmpa_tl
    % start
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c*{\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}{c}@{}}
   }
   {% columns after the first are specified
    \begin{tabular}{@{}c#1@{}}
   }
  \toprule
  % process the rows
  \seq_map_indexed_function:NN \l__fajar_enumtabular_body_seq \__fajar_enumtabular_row:nn
  \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__fajar_enumtabular_row:nn
 {
  \int_compare:nTF { #1 == 1 }
   {
    No. & #2 \\ \midrule
   }
   {
    \int_eval:n { #1 - 1 } & #2 \\
   }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{enumtabular}
  Name & Fruit & Qty \\
  Alice & Lemon & 9 \\
  Bob & Durian & 6 \\
  Cindy & Strawberry & 8
\end{enumtabular}

\bigskip

\begin{enumtabular}[llc]
  Name & Fruit & Qty \\
  Alice & Lemon & 9 \\
  Bob & Durian & 6 \\
  Cindy & Strawberry & 8
\end{enumtabular}

\end{document}


